# A dodgy contour integration method giving the correct result

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, divergent-series

Consider the following integral
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh x}dx$$

Using contour integration with some rectangular contour, it is not too hard to show that the integral evaluates to $\pi^2/2$. However, as shown in [this reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1284788/435223), it is apparently possible to get the correct answer using a semi-circular contour in the upper half-plane, despite the fact that the integral over the contour technically doesn't vanish. As the radius of the semi-circular contour tends to infinity, there are an infinite number of poles contained within the contour with residues $i\pi n$ and $-i\pi n$ for $n$ is even and odd respectively. By assuming that the integral on the semi-circular contour vanishes, the residue theorem yields $$I = 2\pi i \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (i\pi n) = -2\pi^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n n = \frac{\pi^2}{2}$$
if we consider that the last series goes to $-1/4$.

Now, despite the fact that the final answer is correct, the method used seems heretical for three reasons:

1. Assuming the integral on the semi-circular contour vanishes when it clearly doesn't on the imaginary axis.
2. Considering an infinite number of poles within the contour (although it's not too hard to accept that the residue theorem can also be used if the number of poles within a contour is countably infinite).
3. Assuming that the last traditionally divergent series actually converges in this context.

Why does this nevertheless yield the correct result? It's a safe assumption that it is not coincidental, since the entire family of integrals
$$I(n) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{\sinh x}\right)^n dx$$
can seemingly be evaluated correctly by using this method, with the only difference being the type of divergent series at the end.

Comment: So that the integral on the semicircle does vanish in the limit, you could instead integrate $z e^{iaz} \operatorname{csch}(z)$, $a>0$, around the contour.  Then use the dominated converge theorem to argue that $$\lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{xe^{iax}}{\sinh(x)} \, \mathrm dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sinh(x)} \, \mathrm dx. $$

Comment: @RandomVariable I believe that the integral on the semicircle does not vanish.  In fact, it seems to grow in absolute value linearly with the radius.

Comment: @MarkViola   If the radius is increased in a discrete manner so that the semicircle stays a fixed distance away from the poles of $\operatorname{csch}(z)$, then the integral will vanish since $|\operatorname{csch}(z)|$ decays exponentially to zero as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$, and $|e^{iaz}|$, $a>0$,  decays exponentially to zero as $\Im(z) \to + \infty$. It's more obvious if you use a rectangular contour.

Comment: @RandomVariable But can that really be the case when the sum of the residues diverges (quite badly).  See my posted solution and feel free to tear into it if I've made an error.

Comment: @MarkViola   You didn't make an error.  If $a>0$, the sum of the residues converges.  If $a=0$, then it diverges, and we get the situation that you showed.

Comment: @RandomVariable Ah, I didn't read your commnet correctly.  You never claimed that the integral of the original integrand over the "infintie" semi-circle converges.  You only claimed that the regularized integral does.  Got it now.  Apology for my confusion.

Comment: Makes sense. Didn't know about regularization!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering that zeta-regularization applied to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n n$ yields the correct answer, we may attempt to regularize the integral first and then appeal to the principle of analytic continuation.

In this pursuit, it doesn't really matter if we use a semicircular contour or rectangular contour. (Indeed, continuously deforming a contour while avoiding the singularities does not change the value of a contour integral.) What matters most is the fact that the sum of residues diverges as the contour encompasses larger region.  So, we will stick to rectangular contours.

First, we introduce a parameter $s$ and note that

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2 \lim_{s \to 1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= 2 \lim_{s \to 1} J(s),
\end{align*}

where $J(s)$ is defined for *all* $s \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$ by

$$ J(s) = \frac{1}{1 - e^{2\pi i s}} \int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{z^s}{\sinh z} \, \mathrm{d}z $$

and $\mathcal{C}$ is the clockwise-oriented Hankel contour, composed of a small circle about $0$ and two half-infinite lines "just right" above and below the positive $x$-line:

[image: Hankel contour]

Now replace each of the two half-infinite lines by a line segment of length $R$ , and denote the resulting "truncated" Hankel contour by $\mathcal{C}_R$.

[image: Truncated Hankel contour]

Then we may write $J(s)$ as

$$ J(s) = \lim_{R\to\infty} J_R(s),
\qquad\text{where}\qquad
J_R(s) := \frac{1}{1 - e^{2\pi i s}} \int_{\mathcal{C}_R} \frac{z^s}{\sinh z} \, \mathrm{d}z. $$

From this point on, we assume $-2 < \operatorname{Re}(s) < -1$ and $R = (N+\frac{1}{2})\pi$ for $N = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$. Then, as we continuously inflate the contour $\mathcal{C}_R$ to a clockwise-oriented square $\mathcal{S}_R$ with vertices $\pm R \pm iR$, the deformation will sweep poles of the integrand at $z = \pm \pi i, \pm 2\pi i, \ldots, \pm N\pi i$. Hence,

\begin{align*}
J_R(s)
&= \frac{2\pi i}{1 - e^{2\pi i s}} \biggl[ \sum_{n = \pm 1, \ldots, \pm N} \,\underset{z=n\pi i}{\mathrm{Res}}\, \frac{z^s}{\sinh z} + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\mathcal{S}_R} \frac{z^s}{\sinh z} \, \mathrm{d}z\biggr] \\
&= \frac{2\pi i}{1 - e^{2\pi i s}} \biggl[ \pi^s (e^{i\pi s/2} + e^{3i\pi s/2}) \sum_{n = 1}^{N} (-1)^n n^s + \mathcal{O}(N^{1+\operatorname{Re}(s)}) \biggr] \\
&= \frac{\pi^{s+1}}{\sin(\pi s/2)} \sum_{n = 1}^{N} (-1)^{n-1} n^s + \mathcal{O}(N^{1+\operatorname{Re}(s)}).
\end{align*}

So, as $N \to \infty$, it follows that

\begin{align*}
J(s)
&= \frac{\pi^{s+1}}{\sin(\pi s/2)} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} n^s \\
&= \frac{\pi^{s+1}}{\sin(\pi s/2)} (1 - 2^{1+s}) \zeta(-s).
\end{align*}

However, since $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ is connected and both sides of the above equality are holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ that agree on a non-empty open subset, they must agree on all of $\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z}$ by the principle of analytic continuation. This justifies OP's heuristics, and in particular,

$$ I = 2 \lim_{s \to 1} J(s)
= \frac{2\pi^2}{\sin(\pi/2)} (1 - 2^{2}) \zeta(-1)
= \frac{\pi^2}{2}. $$

---

**Addendum.** The above argument also shows that, for any $\operatorname{Re}(s) > 0$,

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{\pi^{s+1}}{\sin(\pi s/2)} (1 - 2^{1+s}) \zeta(-s) $$

On the other hand, the left-hand side can be easily computed as:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^s}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^s e^{-(2n+1)x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(s+1)}{(2n+1)^{s+1}} \\
&= 2 \Gamma(s+1) (1 - 2^{-s-1}) \zeta(s+1).
\end{align*}

Comparing both sides, we get

$$ \zeta(-s)
= - \frac{2 \Gamma(s+1)}{(2\pi)^{s+1}} \zeta(s+1) \sin(\pi s/2) 
$$

and this is just the Riemann's functional equation for $\zeta(\cdot)$ in disguise.

Comment: Why do you also specify $-2<\Re s$? As far as I can see, $\Re s<-1$ is necessary for the asymptotics and so long as $J(s)$ is defined - which it is - your method would work for, e.g., $s=-3$

Comment: @FShrike, You are right. To invoke analytic continuation in my argument, all we need is to find an infinite subset of $\Omega=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{Z} : \operatorname{Re}(z)<-1\}$ that has an accumulation point in $\Omega$. The choice $-2<\operatorname{Re}(z)<-1$ was more or less for convenience.

Comment: I don't quite follow how the Hankel contour was inflated into a square contour, as well as how $J_R (s)$ equals the sum of residues and the integral over the square. Other than that, very neat answer.

Comment: @Zadig. Imagine the (truncated) Hankel contour is a 2D-version of a deflated balloon in a box and the poles are small round balls so that the balloon cannot reach all the way down to the pole but can only wrap around it. Then, as you blow air to the balloon, it will inflate and fill in the space inside the box that is outside of the poles. That is what I envisioned when I made that part of residue computation.

Answer (score 6):

We wish to evaluate the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\,dx$ using contour integration with a contour that is closed in the upper-half plane by a semi-circular arc.

One way to proceed is to close the upper-half plane with a semi-circular contour of radius $(N+1/2)\pi$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C}\frac{z}{\sinh(z)}\,dz&=\int_{-(N+1/2)\pi}^{(N+1/2)\pi}\frac{x}{\sinh(x)}\\\\
&+\int_0^\pi \frac{(N+1/2)\pi e^{i\phi}}{\sinh((N+1/2)\pi e^{i\phi})}\,i(N+1/2)\pi e^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=-2\pi^2  \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n n\\\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}2 - \frac{\pi^2}{2}(-1)^N(2N+1)
\end{align}$$

Now, it shouldn't be difficult to show that

$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\left(\int_0^\pi \frac{i(N+1/2)^2\pi^2 e^{i2\phi}}{\sinh((N+1/2)\pi e^{i\phi})}\,d\phi+\pi^2(-1)^N(N+1/2)\right)=0$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $N$ be a positive integer.

To make the approach rigorous, we can integrate  the modified function $$f(z) = \frac{z e^{iaz}}{\sinh z}, \quad  a >0,  $$ around the same contour, that is,  a contour consisting of the real axis from $-(N+1/2)$ to $(N+1/2)$ and the semicircle above it.

The integral will vanish along the semicircle as $N \to \infty$ through the positive integers because the magnitude of $\sinh(z)$ grows exponentially as $\Re(z) \to \pm \infty$, while the magnitude of $e^{iaz}$ decays exponentially to zero as $\Im(z) \to + \infty$.

Therefore,  we have $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x e^{iax}}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm dx = 2 \pi i \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\operatorname{Res}[f(z), i n \pi] = 2 \pi^{2}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}n e^{-a n \pi} = 2 \pi^2 \, \frac{e^{-a \pi}}{(1+e^{-a \pi})^{2}}. $$

But since  $x e^{iax} \operatorname{csch}(x)$ is dominated on $(-\infty, \infty)$ by the integrable function $x \operatorname{csch}(x)$, we have $$\begin{align} \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{x e^{iax}}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{x}{\sinh x} \, \mathrm dx \\  &=  2 \pi^{2}\lim_{a \to 0^{+} } \frac{e^{- a \pi }}{(1+e^{-a \pi})^{2}} \\   &= \frac{\pi^{2}}{2}. \end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) Nicely written as always

Comment: @MarkViola   I've gone from thinking my approach didn't answer the question, to thinking that it sort of answered the question, to now realizing that it answers the question in a fairly direct manner.

Comment: In effect, the regularization makes rigorous what the OP referenced.