# Evaluating $2\pi i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ine^{-an\pi}}{\cosh(in\pi)}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was trying to evaluate the sum given in the title from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4639131/995613), $a>0$ :
$$\begin{align}A&=2\pi i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{ine^{-an\pi}}{\cosh(in\pi)}}\\
&=2\pi^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}ne^{-an\pi}}\end{align}$$

With the fact that :

$$\begin{align}-\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^nnx^{n-1}}\\
\implies \frac{x}{(1+x)^2}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n-1}nx^n}\end{align}$$

So it seemed natural that $x=e^{-a\pi}$ and $$A\overset{?}{=}\frac{2\pi^2e^{-a\pi}}{(1+e^{-a\pi})^2}$$

But instead the answer given has $e^{a\pi}$ in the place of $e^{-a\pi}$. Why is this? I thought it could be from the condition on the geometric series that $|x|<1$ but that only means $a>0$ which is already given.

Comment: I don't know why I wrote it like that.  I probably should edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your answer and the one given in the other post are identical. To prove this, factor out $e^{-a\pi}$ from the denominator. Hope this helps!